# How to know which component my mouse is hovering over in GWT? [JAVA]

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT based Application and when my mouse hovers over an element, I want getClass() method to be fired over that particular element to display the class name in TooTip. I want to automate this process for every element on my page. Hence, if I could have a method which could tell me which element my mouse hovers over my job would be done. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Adam's excellent answer, built to function in the exact opposite way - instead of looking at each Widget's root element and tweaking it, this watches the `mouseover` event on the entire document, and tries to figure out which widget it is in, though I didn't actually implement the tooltip, just a console.log message for the moment.

The principle is to start at the element where the event happened, and check each parent until a Widget is found to be attached to it, and then log that detail (or, if no parent is found which matches this, stop.

Two small advantages of this approach: it doesn't change the `title` attribute of each Widget's element, and it works even on widgets added after it is initially set up, instead of requiring that it be re-run. Downsides: This makes some assumptions about how the widgets are attached, using GWT internals rather than actually traversing the widget hierarchy, and it may log some UIObjects or other event handlers (though these are rarely something other than Widget, and if this behavior is truly not desired, an `instanceof Widget` check could be added).

```
    Event.addNativePreviewHandler(e -> {
        // Listen to all events before a widget gets the chance, only handle the "mouseover".
        // Depenending on which ToolTip is used, a "mouseout" handler might be desirable too,
        // to hide the tooltip, or else just use a single instance and move it around the page
        // as needed
        if (e.getTypeInt() != Event.ONMOUSEOVER) {
            return;
        }

        // If the event somehow happens to a non-element, ignore
        EventTarget eventTarget = e.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
        if (!Element.is(eventTarget)) {
            return;
        }

        // examine each node up the hierarchy until a parent is found, or we run out of options
        Element elt = eventTarget.cast();
        // Could also add that instanceof check here, ignore non-Widgets
        while (DOM.getEventListener(elt) == null) {
            elt = elt.getParentElement();
            if (elt == null) {
                // give up
                return;
            }
        }

        // Whatever we've found is attached to that element to handle events like a widget would.
        // Other examples include UIObjects (like tree nodes) or GQuery event listeners
        Object attachedObject = DOM.getEventListener(elt);

        // Log it (assumes elemental2, could just as easily use GWT.log()
        // but really should be replaced by your preferred ToolTip
        DomGlobal.console.log(attachedObject.getClass());
    });
```

This could also fairly easily be implemented in plain JS, to allow inspecting a running GWT application that uses Widgets - getEventListener is just looking for a `__listener` property on the element, and most of the other lines translate more or less directly to JS. The `getClass()` method is the only problematic one, depending on how the application is compiled.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. That saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little program that does what you want.

The idea is to traverse the widget tree (from the parent through all child widgets) recursively. For each visited widget you can call

```
widget.setTitle(widget.getClass().getName());
```

to get its class name displayed as a tool-tip.

Here is the code:

```
private void traverse(Widget widget) {
    widget.setTitle(widget.getClass().getName());
    if(widget instanceof HasWidgets) {
        Iterator<Widget> iter = ((HasWidgets) widget).iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
            traverse(iter.next());
    }
    else
        if(widget instanceof HasOneWidget)
            traverse(((HasOneWidget) widget).getWidget());
}
```

It goes deeper to the child widgets checking whether the parent widget is an instance of [`HasWidgets`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasWidgets.html) or [`HasOneWidget`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasOneWidget.html).

Just call this method with the `RootPanel` as a top level widget and it should add a tool-tip to all widgets on the page:

```
traverse(RootPanel.get());
```

Here is a print-screen of the result of running this method on [this example](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwBasicText) (notice the tool-tip displaying `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PasswordTextBox`):

[image]